# What is the value of this integral whose integrand is a mixture of gamma and gaussian functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I am wondering the value of the following integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t(t+1)}} \exp{ \left\lbrace -\left[t+ \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}} - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \right] \right\rbrace } dt.$$
The exponential part is hard to deal with.

Comment: With numerics: $1.3020565684663467160403769532557649948509107721617250304073$

Comment: Is it possible to have a special function or formula as the result of this integral rather than a numerical result?